# Calculation vs Estimation. What is the difference and when to use each of them?

Tags: estimation, terminology

Many times in books/articles I see terms "Calculation" and "Estimation". What is the difference between these two terms and when to use each of them?

Comment: Currently we have over [50,000 posts referring to estimates and estimation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=estimat*%20) that will help you understand these terms.  For the meaning of "calculation," any good dictionary will do--it's not a special term of art in statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*From reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/bxld2i/calculation_vs_estimation_what_is_the_difference/*

You *estimate* the population mean from the sample.

You *calculate* the population mean from full enumeration.

Generally calculation is for a known quantity and an estimation had variance attached to it.

But to confuse things calculation is sometimes used just to describe manipulating numbers. E.g. I did a calculation of the s.d of the mean.

---

*Calculation* will result a Certain answer , but *Estimation* is a calculation which we are not certain about the answer and the answer is probability most time more than 90%.

We can calculate how many unemployment exist in percent. For example, 20% ( we are sure about this number as we divide number to the total.)

But we cannot calculate how many unemployment will be next year. We estimate it . It maybe be 30% (and we are not sure cause many thing may change during the time)

Answer (score 2):

Estimated values will not change if the condition of the frame or population in study does not change. In the above cited example the unemployment of 30% is just an estimation based on the assumption of population growth and many people becoming eligible for employment. We also can calculate unemployment but for that we need extensive data collection and interpretation which need resources and time. Estimation is a shortcut way of taking close to the real value.